# How can you store a Control in a class and reuse it in a binding?

Tags: c#, exception, controls, winui-3

I am trying to reuse NumberBoxes for a GridView because having the NumberBoxes embedded directly in the GridView data template causes undesirable behavior, while reusing them does not. The problem is that I keep getting exceptions. They say "No installed components were detected" on the following line `(templateRoot.FindName("NumberBox") as GridViewItem).Content = item.NumberBox;` in this context

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The callback for updating a container in the GridView named CardGridView.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="args"></param>
private void UpdateGridViewContainer(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Phase == 1)
    {
        Grid templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
        CardItem item = args.Item as CardItem;
        (templateRoot.FindName("NumberBox") as GridViewItem).Content = item.NumberBox;

        TypedEventHandler<NumberBox, NumberBoxValueChangedEventArgs> handler =
            (box, args) =>
            {
                if (!double.IsNaN(args.NewValue))
                {
                    _viewModel.ChangeCount(args, item);
                }
            };

        item.SetHandler(handler);
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown when the Page that contains the GridView is left and renavigated to. I have tried nulling out the NumberBoxes when the page is left, but that did not work. Well, it appeared to before the issue cropped up again.

This is the code that nulls out the NumberBoxes

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Creates new NumberBoxes for when this Page is loaded again.
/// </summary>
private void ResetNumberBoxes()
{
    foreach (CardItem card in CardGridView.Items.Cast<CardItem>())
    {
        card.ResetNumberBox();
    }
    CardGridView.ItemsSource = null;
    CardGridView.Items.Clear();
}
```

ResetNumberBox is just setting the NumberBox to null and assigning a new one.

The exception details

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x800F1000
  Message=No installed components were detected. (0x800F1000)
  Source=WinRT.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.IContentControlMethods.set_Content(IObjectReference _obj, Object value)
```

An update. I have removed the GridViewItem control from the DataTemplate and tried doing the following with the same result

```cs
CardItem item = args.Item as CardItem;

Grid.SetColumn(item.NumberBox, 1);
item.NumberBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
item.NumberBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
(templateRoot.FindName("GridViewTemplate") as Grid).Children.Add(item.NumberBox);
```

I also examined a heap dump right before the line that throws, and there was only one instance of the Grid, and the NumberBox had a parent of null.

Comment: Seems like there can be multiple causes about this: https://www.google.com/search?q=No+installed+components+were+detected.+(0x800F1000)

Comment: Yea, I have Googled, but the stuff I have looked at is unrelated.

Comment: There are a handful of answers in SO, too many to cite, did you try looking/applying them?

Comment: Yea, and they all have additional messages with the Exception that I do not have, and they do not appear to apply in my case. I have checked the output and examined the Exception, but no useful message, just the message and the stack trace above.

Comment: I'm not sure if ```(templateRoot.FindName("NumberBox") as GridViewItem).Content = item.NumberBox;``` should work. I guess you should try fix "undesirable behavior" with NumberBoxes, or try using the ItemsRepeater, which has built-in virtualizing.

Comment: If you need to do it this way anyway, can you share more code around how you are passing items to the GridView? XAML around the GridView also might help.

Comment: I realized how [not cool] my design was, and moved the NumberBoxes to the Page where they belong, so they were in the UI layer instead of the model layer, and lo and behold, the Exceptions stopped.